# Laravel: eloquent relationship create multi

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

i have a ParentItem model

```
$parentItem = ParentItem::get()->first();
```

I have this array

```
$items = array(
 array(
  'title' => 'test1',
  'desc' => 'test1'
 ),
 array(
  'title' => 'test2',
  'desc' => 'test2'
 )
);
```

i want to add it as a has many relationship.
so i can do:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
 $parentItem->items()->create($item)
}
```

is there any way way to create all at once..?
something like:

```
$parentItem->items()->createMany($items);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `createMany` method? Also, you could get the parent model like this: `$parentItem = ParentItem::first();`. This will only retrieve one item from the database. The way you are doing it now gets all the entries in the database and then uses PHP to grab the first item in the collection.

Answer (score 7):

You can tryout two path.

**Using `saveMany` method:**

```
$parentItem = ParentItem::first();
$items = array(
    new Item(['title' => 'test1','desc' => 'test1']),
    new Item(['title' => 'test2','desc' => 'test2'])
);
$parentItem->items()->saveMany($items)
```

For further info you can read here.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

**Using `insert` method:**

```
$parentItem = ParentItem::first();
$items = array(
    array('title' => 'test1','desc' => 'test1','parent_item_id' => $parentItem->id),
    array('title' => 'test2','desc' => 'test2','parent_item_id' => $parentItem->id)
);
Item::insert($items);
```

Remember in insert `created_at` and `updated_at` won't be inserted automatically, you have to provide them in the `array` if you have them in your table. For further info you can read here.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#inserts

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, you may use the `createMany` Eloquent method to achieve this.

Details here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method